# C# multiple attribute to single custom attribute

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I have a azure function (HTTP trigger) which uses attributes of the OpenApi NuGet package.
See a example of my function:

```
[FunctionName(nameof(GetTestModel))]
[OpenApiOperation(
    operationId: nameof(GetTestModel),
    Summary = $"Summary")]
[OpenApiParameter(
    name: "id",
    Description = "The Id of the object.",
    Required = true)]
[OpenApiParameter(
    name: nameof(TestRequestModel.TraceId),
    Description = "The TraceId/CorrelationId to use for this request path",
    In = ParameterLocation.Header)]
[OpenApiResponseWithBody(
    HttpStatusCode.OK,
    "application/json",
    typeof(TestResponseModel),
    Description = $"An object containing all information about the retrieved {nameof(TestResponseModel)}.")]
[OpenApiResponseWithBody(
    HttpStatusCode.NotFound,
    "application/json",
    typeof(CustomHttpError),
    Description = "An object containing information about occured errors/exceptions")]
public async Task<ActionResult<TestResponseModel>> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "GET", Route = "test")]
    TestRequestModel request)
{
    // do stuff.
}
```

As you can see that are a lot of attributes.
I would like to reduce it to 1 custom attribute, like this:

```
[FunctionName(nameof(GetTestModel))]
[OpenApiCustom(nameof(GetTestModel), typeof(TestResponseModel), typeof(TestResponseModel)]
public async Task<ActionResult<TestResponseModel>> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "GET", Route = "test")]
    TestRequestModel request)
{
    // do stuff.
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: No. Attributes are metadata. Most of the time they don't do the work themselves. Applications, libraries and runtimes only know about specific attributes and how to handle them. The attributes you want to merge [only contain properties](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-openapi-extension/blob/eab272c235dbfe40fcc27985326a449f90691855/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.Core/Attributes/OpenApiResponseWithBodyAttribute.cs#L11)

Answer (score -1):

This is possible. you can create custom Attributes. with multiple attributes variable but not duplicate.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FunctionApp1
{
    internal class CustomAttribute : Attribute
    {
        private int version;
        private string packagename;
        private string applicationname;
        private string applicationversion;
        public CustomAttribute(string _name, string _address, string _description, int _version, string _packagename, string _applicationname, string _applicationversion)
        {
            this.version = _version;
            this.packagename = _packagename;
            this.applicationname = _applicationname;
            this.applicationversion = _applicationversion;
        }
    }

    public class YourAttribute : Attribute
    {
        private int version;
        private string packagename;
        private string applicationname;
        private string applicationversion;
        public YourAttribute(string _name, string _address,string _description, int _version, string _packagename, string _applicationname, string _applicationversion)
        {
            this.version = _version;
            this.packagename = _packagename;
            this.applicationname = _applicationname;
            this.applicationversion = _applicationversion;
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using NSwag.Annotations;

namespace FunctionApp1
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        [Custom("NameString","AddressString","DescriptionString",1,"ApplicationPackageNamestring","ApplicationNameString","ApplicationVersionString")]
        [Your("NameString", "AddressString", "DescriptionString", 1, "ApplicationPackageNamestring", "ApplicationNameString", "ApplicationVersionString")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            return new OkObjectResult("Successfully");
        }
    }
}
```

[More Information about Creating Custom Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/creating-custom-attributes)